# Simple way to pass temporary struct by value in C++?

Tags: c++, struct, temporary

Suppose I want to pass a temporary object into a function.  Is there a way to do that in 1 line of code vs. 2, with a struct?

---

With a class, I can do:

```
class_func(TestClass(5, 7));
```

given:

```
class TestClass
{
private:
    int a;
    short b;

public:
    TestClass(int a_a, short a_b) : a(a_a), b(a_b)
    {
    }

    int A() const
    {
        return a;
    }

    short B() const
    {
        return b;
    }
};

void class_func(const TestClass & a_class)
{
    printf("%d %d\n", a_class.A(), a_class.B());
}
```

---

Now, how do I do that with a struct?  The closest I've got is:

```
test_struct new_struct = { 5, 7 };
struct_func(new_struct);
```

given:

```
struct test_struct
{
    int a;
    short b;
};

void struct_func(const test_struct & a_struct)
{
    printf("%d %d\n", a_struct.a, a_struct.b);
}
```

The object is more simple, but I wonder if there's a way to do the struct member initialization right in line with the function call, without giving the struct a constructor.  (I don't want a constructor.  The whole reason I'm using a struct is to avoid the boilerplate get/set class conventions in this isolated case.)

Comment: You can still write a constructor keeping the member variables public. So you don't require get/set methods. Is there any problem in doing that?

Comment: Did you mean to achieve the struct initialization in C? In C++ a struct can also do whatever you are doing in the class.

Answer (score 10):

An alternative to providing a constructor in your struct, would be to provide a make_xxx free function:

```
struct Point {int x; int y;};

Point makePoint(int x, int y) {Point p = {x, y}; return p;}

plot(makePoint(12, 34));
```

One reason why you might want to avoid constructors in structs is to allow brace-initialization in arrays of structs:

```
// Not allowed when constructor is defined
const Point points[] = {{12,34}, {23,45}, {34,56}};
```

vs

```
const Point points[] = {Point(12,34), Point(23,45), Point(34,56)};
```

Comment: Note that in C++11, use can use brace-initialization even if the `Point` constructor is defined. In that case, the arguments within the braces will be passed to the constructor. This feature is called [Uniform Initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization).

Answer (score 7):

This is possible in the [C++11 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization). Basically, you are able to do this:

```
struct_func(test_struct{5, 7});
```

This is already available in GCC as of version 4.4.

Comment: In fact, you don't even need to explicitly declare the type, unless there's ambiguity about the types that can be created by the braced init list: `#include <iostream>

struct S {
        int i;
        double d;
};

void f(S s)
{
        std::cout << s.i << ' ' << s.d << std::endl;
}

int main(int, char **)
{
        f( {7, 42} );
}` I don't think I'd ever have gotten by without uniform initialisation or all the other massive upgrades made in C++11 that I completely take for granted.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the same way as you do with the class. Just give your struct a constructor and you can create it inline just like the struct. Your objections about using a constructor are unfounded. The primary difference between a class and a struct is the default visibility associated with it. For classes, it's private; for structs, public. There's no "boilerplate," and you don't have to obey any "conventions" that you don't want to.

```
struct test_struct
{
    int a;
    short b;

    test_struct(int a_, int b_): a(a_), b(b_) { }
};

struct_func(test_struct(5, 7));
```

Comment: @Terry Mahaffey, you definitely can use brace-initialization with a class. The constraints are the same as for struct. The difference between `struct` and `class` keyword *is* default visibility only (for members and base classes). You can even mix the keywords: `struct t {}; class t v;`.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I thought only structs could be PODs for some reason. I withdraw my comment

Answer (score 0):

I'm not c++ expert, but couldn't you just place the creation statement inside the argument list of your function call?

Comment: No, some compilers allow that sort of thing and it's in C++0x (§5.2.3/3) but it's not currently standard.

Answer (score 0):

Structs can also have constructors, so you can do the same thing with them you do with the class example.