# how to declare a function that takes struct as input parameter?

Tags: arrays, struct, c++-cli

```
public:    
array<System::Byte>^ convert_to_byte(struct s)
{
    array<System::Byte>^ a = gcnew array<System::Byte>(5);
    return a;
}
```

gives me :

> Error  1   error C2027: use of undefined type 'my_make_data::s'

Comment: Can you give us the definition of the struct? Where you have convert_to_byte(struct s), it's possible that there should be the name of the struct.

Comment: @Cyber Yes, probably. That `^` managed pointer and `operator gcnew` don't seem standard.

Comment: have you defined that `struct s`? if you have, please give us some reference to that struct, else define it before you use it :)

Comment: Take a look [here][1] it might help you out!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181765/passing-structs-to-functions

Answer (score 0):

`struct s` shall be defined outside the function.

Also it is not clear why it is present in the function definition as a parameter type specifier when no object of this type is  used within the function body.