# C++ Passing an array of struct as function argument

Tags: c++, function, struct, parameters

C++: What's the difference between the code as shown below AND simultaneously omitting the keyword `struct` in the functional declaration and definition -- code seems to work the same both ways ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct student{
            int age;
            int number;
        };

void printme( struct student m[]);    // if 'struct' is omitted the code works as fine

int main()
{        
    student s[3];
    s[0].age = 10;
    s[0].number = 333;

    printme(s);

    return 0;
}

void printme( struct student m[]){
        printf("George age and number: %d, %d \n", m[0].age, m[0].number);
    }
```

Comment: In C++, there's no difference.

Comment: It's mostly backward compatibility with c - both options are the same.

Comment: Doesn' [this work fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce2d2f77caad639d) actually? I don't get your quesiton.

Comment: Change the keyword `struct` to `class` and you'll see why it works. [C++ Does Not Have Structs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32719880/why-theres-not-stdis-struct-type-trait/34108140#34108140)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ OP is asking why it works _without_ the `struct` keyword in the function declaration.

Comment: @CareyGregory A dupe actually? Should we close that?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't think it's a dup. Very close, but not quite.

Comment: If you make a typo (e.g. `struct studten m[]`) then you get an error message in a different place , or even silent undefined behaviour, depending whether or not you included `struct`

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you are using [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and *not* [c](/questions/tagged/c), so here there is no difference, you can use both of these options.

Check this: [Passing structs to functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181765/passing-structs-to-functions) for more.

Comment: I assume that in C you HAVE TO use the 'struct', while in CPP it's optional ? Probably for code compatibility ? Thanx

Comment: Yes @IvoPeev. In [tag:C], unless you had some `typedef` you would receive a compiler error!

Comment: Why `class` instead of `struct` if both are the same thing?

Comment: _"I would encourage you to use a class instead of a struct"_ Why's that? The keyword `class` and the keyword `struct` both introduce classes.

Comment: @IvoPeev By the way, the language is called C++ (and cpp is the C preprocessor).

Comment: Oh OK @LightnessRacesinOrbit and juanchopanza, edited. :)

Answer (score 0):

This comes from C, where you had to specify struct (or use typedef). In C++, there's no difference *as long as* you don't use the same id for both a struct and an object. Please, don't do it, but if your really want to, then you'll need to write e.g. `struct student` for the type and `student` for the object (which is not necessarily of type student, if you really want to confuse everyone). Basically, C+ coding standards tend to recommend skipping struct and never having the same id for struct and object.